# Can I set a proxy for specific yum repositories?

Tags: yum, proxy, repository

I know I can set a proxy server globally for all repos in `/etc/yum.conf` but can I do it separately for specific repositories?

e.g. this is a line I can put in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
proxy=http://proxysvr.yourdom.com:3128
```

but can I use similar mechanism for `/etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo.repo` ?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try it yet? Should work, according to e.g. https://superuser.com/a/561473/365864 - but see some more examples in the upstream bugreports: [Bug 270521 - yum does not honor per-repo proxy-setting when retrieving repodata](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=270521)
and partly also [Bug 191864 - proxy=*none* in yum.conf has no effect](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=191864)

It also seems to be necessary for yum to specify the proxy with a `/` at the end according to [Bug 200854 - Yum proxy documentation is not correct](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=200854) so in your example:
`proxy=http://proxysvr.yourdom.com:3128/`

Comment: I've been using this approach for a while... in `dnf`.  One or two quirks but I got them reported and fixed now.